# How to keep ProGuard from separating inner enum

Tags: java, enums, proguard, inner-classes, android-proguard

I am trying to ProGuard a public-facing class (`MyClass`) file containing an inner enum (`MyInnerEnum`). However, after ProGuarding, the inner enum is separated out into its own class file `MyClass$MyInnerEnum`. How can I prevent ProGuard from separating out the inner enum? I need to be able to access the inner enum using dot notation, like `MyClass.MyInnerEnum.ENUM_VALUE` and not using the dollar sign like `MyClass$MyInnerEnum.ENUM_VALUE`.

My public-facing class:

```
package com.myclass;

public interface MyClass {
    enum MyInnerEnum {
        ENUM_VALUE
    }
}
```

I've tried these ProGuard configuration options to no avail:

```
<option>-keep enum com.myclass.MyClass** { *; }</option>
<option>-keep enum com.myclass.MyClass$* { *; }</option>
<option>-keep enum com.myclass.MyClass$MyInnerEnum { *; }</option>
```

Comment: It is standard behaviour to put nested classes into a separate `.class` file, it is unrelated to proguard. You should still be able to use the dot.

Comment: Nested classes always break out into separate classes in bytecode using the `Outer$Nested` naming pattern. That is Java compilation, per the documentation for Java. That doesn't alter how one refers to nested classes in source. And that is not an "inner enum", it's a nested enum. Interfaces can't have inner classes. JLS §9.5: "A member type declaration in an interface is implicitly `public` and `static`." JLS §8.9: "A nested enum type is implicitly `static`."

Comment: lets say it different, the java virtual machine does not know nested classes, in other words, there is no way to have a nested class a byte code level. (It is just a *trick* of the compiler that adds some variables and access methods so the compiled class works as a nested one). Not using Proguard will result in same structure.

Comment: You cannot "prevent Proguard" from doing that because it is not Proguard that does that.  It's the java compiler that does that.  Moreover, since nested enums are static by definition (Lew Bloch's comment), there is no point at all to have them nested.  You can "prevent the singling out" by doing it yourself in source.

Answer (score 1):

You can give it a try by keeping the outer class (in your case interface) and the inner enum. By adding the following lines to your proguard config, this should work:

```
-keep interface com.myclass.MyClass
-keep enum com.myclass.MyClass$MyInnerEnum
```

Answer (score 1):

I meet the same problem. I resolve it by adding:

```
# don't proguard all inner enum, need to cooperate with "-keep enum com.companyname.abcd.ClassName$EnumName"
-keepattributes InnerClasses
...
-keep enum com.myclass.MyClass$MyInnerEnum
```